# Show the Elements from ArrayList of map ,in list form in Android

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a A data stored in **ArrayList< HashMap< String, String> >** retrieved from JSON 
in the form (i.e.)

```
[{price: =1685 name: =Monographie Der Gattung Pezomachus (Grv.) by Arnold F.    Rster}]
```

And I need to show the all map elements into list form in Android.
I've tried many ways but I'm unable to do it .

Also help me to know about the layouts to use in it

EDITED:

```
MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(myarr_list);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

And in the MySimpleArrayAdapter Class, in Constructor

```
public MySimpleArrayAdapter( ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> pl) {
LayoutInflator inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

The control does not proceed after this,
MySimpleArrayAdapter Class

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ProductList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


    //Constructor
    public MySimpleArrayAdapter( ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> pl) {

        this.ProductList = pl;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }





    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View myview = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_search_result, null);
        }


        TextView price = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.price);
        TextView name = (TextView) myview.findViewById(R.id.name);



        HashMap<String, String> pl = new HashMap<String, String>();
        pl = ProductList.get(position);
        //Setting 
        price.setText(pl.get("price"));
        name.setText(pl.get("name"));
        return myview;

    }


}
```

I am editing here a onPostExecute class from  SearchResultsTask extended by  AsyncTask

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

            if (json != null && json.length() > 0) {
                try {                   
                JSONArray json_results = (JSONArray)(json.get("results"));               
                String parsedResult = "";
                System.out.println("-> Size ="+ json_results.length());


                    for(int i = 0; i < json_results.length(); i++){         
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject json_i = json_results.getJSONObject(i);


                        map.put("name: ",json_i.getString("name") + "\n");
                        map.put("price: ",json_i.getString("price") + "\n");    
                        arr_list.add(map);

                    }                        
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("-> Size =====arr_llist ="+ arr_list.size());
        //  CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter (arr_list);
            //final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this, R.id.result, arr_list);
        //  listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            MyListActivity obj1 = new MyListActivity();
            Bundle icicle = null;
            obj1.onCreate(icicle); 


        }
    public class MyListActivity extends Activity {

          public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            //  System.out.println("In my list Activity");
            // super.onCreate(icicle);

            //populate list
           MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this,arr_list);
            //  System.out.println("in 2");

           adapter.getView(0, listview, listview);
           listview.setAdapter(adapter);
          }


    }
```

Comment: Show us your many ways you have tried, but unsucceded

Comment: And show us the code of your adapter

Comment: MySimpleArrayAdapter#getView(){
// p is the position, you will get it from args of getView()
 HashMap<String, String> yourMapAtIndexP = yourList.get(P);
String key = "your key value";
String valueToShow = yourMapAtIndexP.get(key);
// Now display it in whatever view you want
}

Comment: @GauravGupta , I cant get through this 
inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

Comment: hey @GauravGupta, my map structure is like `{name: =Monographie Der Gattung Pezomachus (Grv.) by Arnold F.Rster, price: =1685}
` and i cant access these values by your method . Help me ..!
I did this 
`System.out.println(mylist.get("price"));
  System.out.println(mylist.get("name"));` and it gives `null`

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ProductList.size() ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   //Constructor
    public MySimpleArrayAdapter( ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> pl, Context c) {

        this.ProductList = pl;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
```

getSystemService() is method of context, you are calling it on instance of adapter.

Comment: What should I pass in this Constructor (i.e  which Context)?
I tried using this , this.getBaseContext , getApplicationContext .....

Comment: you can pass `this` of the Activity. That is activity context.

Comment: I have provided my OnPostExecuteTask and calling of MySimpleArayAdapter in the qstn asked above 
Please find it

Comment: You are ruining the activity life cycle. life-cycle callback are provided by f/w, you are calling your self. So, context won't be initialized by that time. I recommend you to re-visit the android tutorial and check out the life-cycle.
you will also find custom adapter implementation on vogella. 
Your code needs to be restructured.

Comment: Help me out brother in restructuring it plz .